# How do I used distinct to remove duplicates in this query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have the following table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF55W.png)

I am trying to write a query (that I will include in another query) to display how many account numbers there are per symbol.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT Symbol,
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT([Account Number]) FROM [Open] T2 WHERE T2.Symbol = T1.Symbol) AS Accounts
FROM Open T1
GROUP BY [Symbol];
```

The query displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exWUo.png) but it counts the same account number multiple times per symbol. EURUSD should have 3 and USDJPY should only have 1 next to it.

It should display like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDdE1.png).

I am trying to include this as part of another big table that has other information next to each symbol too.

I will appreciate any assistance.

Comment: SELECT count without GROUP By will return 1 value there is nothing to DISTINCT. So please add create table and data as text and show what result you want

Comment: @nbk I have added a table. I am not sure why it wasn't working with Stack Overflow formatting so I just added a photo. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't support `count(DISTINCT ...)`. You can try

```
SELECT Symbol, count(*) AS Accounts
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Symbol, Account FROM Open) 
 GROUP BY Symbol;
```

Comment: this query worked but I have a follow up. I already have an existing table that has  GROUP BY Symbol and it has other columns with data. How would I add this query to that table?

Comment: Depends on the query and the desired result. Usually you either JOIN it or 'add its result' to the results of this query using an UNION.